# Youtube API: Can I skip pages? (playlistItems)

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

Is it possible to skip pages with the Youtube API v3?

If I call this: `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems` (which returns the items from a certain playlist), I get a `nextPageToken` and `previousPageToken` for navigation...

How can I skip pages?

If I'm standing on page 1, and there are 30 pages (maxResults: 50, totalResults: 1500), ... how can I go directly to page 28? am I forced to do 28 HTTP requests?

Answer (score 0):

They do limit the API to returning 500 results and I've only tested this through about 200 playlist items, but in case it's of some use, I shared the algorithm that I'm using to generate page tokens here:

[Youtube Data API v3 pageToken for arbitrary page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30949556/youtube-data-api-v3-pagetoken-for-arbitrary-page)