# Youtube Data API v3 pageToken for arbitrary page

Tags: php, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Another question on SO revealed that pageTokens are identical for different searches, provided that the page number and maxResults settings are the same.

Version 2 of the API let you go to any arbitrary page by setting a start position, but v3 only provides next and previous tokens. There's no jumping from page 1 to page 5, even if you know there are 5 pages of results.

So how do we work around this?

Answer (score 14):

A YouTube pageToken is six characters long. Here's what I've been able to determine about the format:

char 1: Always 'C' that I've seen.
char 2-3: Encoded start position
char 4-5: Always 'QA' that I've seen.
char 6: 'A' means list items in a position greater than or equal to the start position. 'Q' means list items before the start position.

Due to the nature of character 6, there are two different ways to represent the same page. Given maxResults=1, page 2 can be reached by setting the page token to either "CAEQAA" or "CAIQAQ". The first one means to start at result number 2 (represented by characters 2-3 "AE") and list 1 item. The second means to return one item before result number 3 (represented by characters 2-3 "AI".

Characters 2-3 are a strange base 16 encoding.

Character 3 uses a list from A-Z, then a-z, then 0-9 and increments by 4 in the list for each increase of 1. The series is A,E,I,M,Q,U,Y,c,g,k,o,s,w,0,4,8. Character 2 goes from A to B to C to D and so on. For my purposes, I'm not working with large result sets, so I haven't bothered to see what happens to the second character beyond a couple hundred results. Perhaps someone working with larger sets will provide an update as to how character 2 behaves after that.

Since the string only contains a start position and an option for ">=" or "<", the same string is used in multiple cases. For instance, with 2 results per page, the start position of the second page is result 3. The pageToken for this is "CAIQAA". This is identical to the token for the third page with one result per page.

Since I'm primarily a php person, here's the function I'm using to get the pageToken for a given page:

```
function token($limit, $page) {
    $start = 1 + ($page - 1) * $limit;
    $third_chars = array_merge(
            range("A","Z",4),
            range("c","z",4),
            range(0,9,4));
    return 'C'.
           chr(ord('A') + floor($start / 16)).
           $third_chars[($start % 16) - 1].
           'QAA';
}
$limit = 1;
echo "With $limit result(s) per page...".PHP_EOL;
for ($i = 1; $i < 6; ++$i) {
    echo "The token for page $i is ".token($limit, $i).PHP_EOL;
}
```

Please test this function in your project and update the rest of us if you find a flaw or an enhancement since YouTube hasn't provided us with an easy way to do this.

Edit: The page token sequence for YouTube API v3 has been changed, and this system will no longer work. For an example of the most up-to-date and working page tokens, see [this page](https://github.com/thomas-xin/Miza/blob/dabf27408effa1d5a44e09f73b1ad7dddc2a1452/misc/page_tokens.txt).

Comment: This is pretty impressive to me ... some good reverse engineering. After 500 results, the API stops giving nextPageTokens, so there's a finite limit on how far the pattern you need to prove out.

Answer (score 7):

YouTube's pagetokens can be treated as indices.

- Pagetokens for the first 1000 items can be found [here](https://github.com/Quihico/handy.stuff/blob/master/yt.pagetokens.00000-00999).
- Pagetokens for every 10th item in range(1, 100000) can be found [here](https://github.com/Quihico/handy.stuff/blob/master/yt.pagetokens.x10).
- The highest available pagetoken is "CJ-NBhAA" which points to the 100.000th item with position 99.999.
- The highest possible value for maxresults is 50.

Use pagetoken to specify a starting point and maxresults to specify the number of items.

Examples:

- 1st item

`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=id%2Csnippet&playlistId=<PLAYLISTID>&key=<APIKEY>&maxResults=1&pageToken=CAAQAA`

- 555th item

`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=id%2Csnippet&playlistId=<PLAYLISTID>&key=<APIKEY>&maxResults=1&pageToken=CKoEEAA`

- 99999th item

`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=id%2Csnippet&playlistId=<PLAYLISTID>&key=<APIKEY>&maxResults=1&pageToken=CJ6NBhAA`

- 10 items starting at 10th item

`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=id%2Csnippet&playlistId=<PLAYLISTID>&key=<APIKEY>&maxResults=10&pageToken=CAkQAA`

- 30 items starting at 555th item

`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=id%2Csnippet&playlistId=<PLAYLISTID>&key=<APIKEY>&maxResults=30&pageToken=CKoEEAA`

- 50 items starting at 9999th item

`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=id%2Csnippet&playlistId=<PLAYLISTID>&key=<APIKEY>&maxResults=50&pageToken=CI9OEAA`

Comment: page token list of 50 item per page.

Comment: If you are asking for a list of pagetokens for every 50th item, you can use the list [here](https://github.com/Quihico/handy.stuff/blob/master/yt.pagetokens) which contains all available pagetokens (100000)

Comment: How to create pagination link for youtube api total results

Comment: @QuihicoSanchezvanOort Could you update this for the new page token format?

Answer (score 1):

Using ^ Quihico's files as a reference point, I had a little fun writing an enhancement to the previous poster's pageToken generator, in JS. If my assumption is correct about how the 4000s place encoding varies past N >= 98304, it *should* be able to construct a pageToken for a page starting with Nth item, provided N in [0, 4194304). It's only tested up to N = 99999, so YMMV.

Link here: https://github.com/aricearice/youtube-page-token/blob/master/index.js

Answer (score 0):

An addendum to thatthatisis's answer, the linked token list is specifically for maxResults=10. I exported a complete list for the currently maximum allowed value for maxResults, 50:
https://github.com/Koushakur/randomStuff/blob/main/YouTube%20API%20pageTokens%20for%20maxResults%3D50.txt

I call it 'complete' because the API just looped around after the last token in the list to the first page even though I used a upload playlist of a channel with a million videos on it to grab the tokens, so it seems like the maximum size of a playlist is about 20700 videos.