# Is pagination for Youtube API Channel Memberships (sponsors.list) broken?

Tags: youtube-data-api

I'm trying to paginate through a list of results using the youtube API for Channel Memberships (sponsors.list), but the paging and PageTokens don't seem to be working as they are supposed to.

I'm currently developing an application for a user to generate a list of all Members to their channel (using the api for sponsors.list: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/sponsors/list)

I have a test account, and I've been able to successfully pull the list. However, the test account only has 5 memberships. Since the API can only pull a maximum of 50 results per page, I want to make sure that my app can account for the possibility that the channel will have 50+ sponsors.

So, I've set the results per page to give me just 1, theoretically giving me 5 pages I can then sift through to simulate 50+ members.

The problem arises when I try to page through the results... as the API says, I grab the nextPageToken from the results, and pass it in the next call in the pageToken parameter. However, when I do so, even when testing in the API explorer, I get back an empty list, and no nextPageToken for the next page.

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#sponsorListResponse",
 "etag": "\"XpPGQXPnxQJhLgs6enD_n8JR4Qk/UCSC321uKOiUT6GNkcPmkqoH1sY\"",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 0,
  "resultsPerPage": 0
 },
 "items": []
}
```

Additionally, if I pass a fake pageToken, the results come as if I'd passed no token at all, so it is at least recognizing the nextPageToken I'm passing it.

My google searches have failed me, other than just turning up pages talking about how the pagination is supposed to work... which it obviously isn't. Am I doing something wrong? Or is it indeed broken?

***Edit***

Here are the API calls I made.
Initial member list pull (After getting the authorization token, etc).

```
'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/sponsors?part=snippet&filter=all&maxResults=1' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer [SECRET_ACCESS_TOKEN]' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
```

Which results in: (I've edited out sensitive info, like [CHANNEL_ID], etc).

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#sponsorListResponse",
 "etag": "\"XpPGQXPnxQJhLgs6enD_n8JR4Qk/PRgb6wjx--gdhgTtZ1auDKOony0\"",
 "nextPageToken": "GLiawvDS6uEC",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 5,
  "resultsPerPage": 1
 },
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "youtube#sponsor",
   "etag": "\"XpPGQXPnxQJhLgs6enD_n8JR4Qk/LoD6jhrr94l_4soca-7lx14kyRQ\"",
   "snippet": {
    "channelId": "[CHANNEL_ID]",
    "sponsorDetails": {
     "channelId": "[CHANNEL_ID]",
     "channelUrl": "[CHANNEL_URL]",
     "displayName": "[DISPLAY_NAME]",
     "profileImageUrl": "[PROFILE_IMAGE_URL]"
    },
    "sponsorSince": "2019-04-25T06:36:11.677Z"
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

So I grab the `nextPageToken` "GLiawvDS6uEC", and drop that into my next call in the `pageToken` field, as the API instructs.

```
  'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/sponsors?part=snippet&filter=all&maxResults=1&pageToken=GLiawvDS6uEC' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer [SECRET_ACCESS_TOKEN]' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
```

And wind up with this depressing result:

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#sponsorListResponse",
 "etag": "\"XpPGQXPnxQJhLgs6enD_n8JR4Qk/UCSC321uKOiUT6GNkcPmkqoH1sY\"",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 0,
  "resultsPerPage": 0
 },
 "items": []
}
```

Comment: Please post the actual sequence of queries that resulted with the JSON we see above. Nota bene: edit out the API key (that's your private data!)

Comment: Added in the actual queries

Comment: I had some similar issues when using the Google+ API.

Answer (score 1):

So, turns out this was an actual problem with the API. Had a friend who knew someone at google, they looked into it, got the problem fixed! It works as intended now! Yay!

That said, if I hadn't had that connection, who knows if this would ever have been solved ;_;

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, a *nextPageToken* of value `GLiawvDS6uEC` is invalid.

All the page tokens I came across were of a pattern described e.g. by [Youtube Data API v3 pageToken for arbitrary page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30949556/youtube-data-api-v3-pagetoken-for-arbitrary-page).

The API's documentation itself says nothing about how a page token should look like!

Maybe someone else has better inside on this issue. In any case, I suggest to file a report with [Google](http://issuetracker.google.com).

Comment: Google told me to post on Stack Overflow if I need help. ;_;
I also noticed that the tokens looked quite different from others in the API. Interestingly enough, if I put in anything else in the pageToken field *instead* of the token they gave me, it will act as if I gave no token at all. So it does seem to be recognizing the token on some level.

Comment: I checked myself with the [Search endpoint](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) on a valid channel passing a *pageToken* of value ``foobar`` and got a ``400`` error, ``Bad request``.  That is why I suspect that your issue is a *real* API problem.

Comment: OK: there is the issue [report](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/131269064).